# Monitor RAID on a Dell PowerEdge T100

Tags: debian, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

I have a small server Dell PowerEdge T100 with a RAID1 array built with a Dell RAID SAS controller with Debian 5 as s.o.
Is there any way to monitor it, and/or to receive notification about raid errors? Seems that the only method for now is to reboot, enter the SAS utility, and check the array status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have lots of information for you. I see good things in your future.**

The RAID controller will likely have some software that comes with it that will help you monitor it. To tell you for sure, I'd need to know your controller model. Linux may also be aware of the array status through the kernel driver and/or through a utility. Again, I'd need to know more.

It seems you need **OpenManage** if your RAID controller is a **SAS 6/ir** as indicated on the Dell web site. You're version of Debian is very old (5?). We're at 8.5 now. And your server does not officially support Debian.

Discussion about OpenManage with your controller: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19256843

Dell supported operating systems for your server:

```
Novell SuSE Linux ES 11
VMware ESX 3.5
VMware ESX 4.0
VMware ESXi 4.1
VMware ESXi 5.0
Red Hat Ent Linux 4.5
Red Hat Ent Linux 4.6
SuSE Linux ES 9 SP4 x86_64
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.5
Windows Server 2012
Red Hat Ent Linux 4.7
Red Hat Ent Virtual3
Novell SuSE Linux ES 10
VMware ESX 4.1
VMware ESXi 5.1
Red Hat Ent Linux 4
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
Windows Server 2003 x64
Red Hat Ent Linux 5
Windows Server 2012 R2
Suse Linux ES 10
Red Hat Ent Linux 5.2
Windows Server 2003
Windows Server 2008 x86
Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2008 x64
Suse Linux ES 9
```

However, there is a community supported version of **OpenManage** that is **Debian and Ubuntu compatible**: https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/latest/

**Nagios** appears to have a plugin for **OpenManage**: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/check_openmanage/details

I suspect from reading some threads, **this utility** may be compatible with your RAID controller as well (`mpt-status`) and may be all you're looking for (rather than OpenManage). It comes packaged with Debian and Ubuntu.

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/admin/mpt-status

**5/ir** with **Nagios** and **mpt-status** (may be similar): http://tech.pookey.co.uk/monitoring-dell-sas-5ir-raid-with-nagios/

The only other way I can think of monitoring RAID on your system would be if the controller driver exposes status information under `/sys` or `/proc` or somewhere you can access it. You can then use the `Net-SNMP` daemon to do some custom monitoring and then setup something with `nagios` or similar to query the information. Or create a custom `nagios` plugin. There are options as long as you can get the status of the controller.